# How to add declared ints{2,7,23,52,113} to equal user input number?

Tags: java

I really apologize for this lame question. I am new to Java and can't seem to wrap my head around the syntax
I have these ints declared = 2,7,23,52,113 and I need them to add together from the largest to equal the user number

e.g. User inputs int 1000 the program writes that it needs 8x 113, 2x 52 etc.. to get to 1000.

Like if you pay for something 1000, the cashier will give you the largest sums.

I hope it is understandable.

```
    int b1=2;
    int b2=7;
    int b3=23;
    int b4=52;
    int b5=113;

    System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
    int num;
    num = sc.nextInt();
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a sorted array of integers in ascending order, I think following is that you need.

```
    int i = numbers.length-1, count = 0; // Assuming you've an array of int[] say numbers
    while ( i > = 0 && num > numbers[i]) { // num is the value which is entered by a user.
          count = num / numbers[i];
          num %= numbers[i];
          if (num <= numbers[i]) {
              System.out.println ("You'll get " + numbers[i] + "for " + count + " times");
              count = 0;
              i--;
          }
    }
    System.out.println ("The left value is: " + num); // This will print the remaining value, which is smaller than the smallest value of array.
```

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for school, it's important to first think of an algorithm before you bother yourself with the syntax.

For example, you wanna go over the numbers in decreasing order, check how many times the number appear in the input, save it in array, and so on... Once you figure that out, syntax is the easy part.

There you go, something like this should work

```
int[] numbers = {113, 52, 23, 7, 2};
int[] multipliers = new int[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
  multipliers[i] = num / numbers[i];
  num %= numbers[i];
}

if (num != 0) {
  // no solution found
} else {
  // output the multipliers
}
```

Edit: And if you don't want to use loops and arrays:

```
int mult1 = num/b1;
num %= b1;
int mult2 = num/b2;
num %= b2;
...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the feedback. I edited my post because I think it wasn't quite clear what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
int[] b = { b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 };
int res = 0;
for (int i = b.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int k = 0;
    while (res < num) {
        if ((res + b[i]) > num) {
            break;
        }
        res = res + b[i];
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println(k + "x " + b[i]);
}
```

This code snippet will provide the following output when the input is 1000:

```
8x 113
1x 52
1x 23
3x 7
```

If the numbers are not sorted, then it is important to sort the numbers in ascending order for this code to work.

I hope this helps.